# Alternate to sendkeys in VBScript

Tags: database, postgresql, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I am facing some issue with a VBScript which automatically enters the password to Runas command. I am using the following VBScript (runasDBUser.vbs) to execute a program:

```
Option explicit
Dim oShell, k
Const PASSWORD = "DBPassword1~"
set oShell= Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 500
oShell.run("RunAs /noprofile /user:DBUser " & Chr(34) & "cmd /c\" & Chr(34) &       WScript.Arguments(0) & "\" & Chr(34) & Chr(34))
WScript.Sleep 700
oShell.SendKeys (PASSWORD)
Wscript.Quit
```

This script is called in a batch file:

```
cscript //Nologo //B runasDBUser.vbs ""C:postgresql\bin\initdb.exe" --locale=C --encoding=UTF-8  -U %ADMIN_DB% -D "%DATA_DIR%""`
```

This works successfully in some of the Windows servers, but on some, it does not work. Seems like it would not enter the password correctly, and so, the initdb.exe will not run. When I manually enter the password during installation, it works fine. Is there an alternate to sendkeys which I can use to auto-enter the DBUser's password while running the "Runas" command?

Or, is there some other script which someone can suggest which would enter the Runas password automatically? Cannot use third part exe files like psexec.

Comment: For a more secure approach, runas can cache passwords... but you need to enter them at least once, and the password is stored in the current user's profile (i.e.: may not be suitable).

Comment: The DBuser profile is created while the DB is installed and not used otherwise. Also, in order to install the DB from a batch file with no user interaction, I need to automate the password enter process..

Comment: When I messagebox out your run line (using cat.txt as the file name) this is what I get. `RunAs /noprofile /user:DBUser "cmd /c\"cat.txt\""`. Also things that don't return values don't have brackets. Backslash is not an escape in basic (doesn't have one) or batch (^).

Comment: @phd443322 `\"` is properly used to surround the argument of a command passed to `RunAs`. Check the `RunAs` help docs.

Comment: @user3669651 You said you can't use _third party_ files. So does that mean other Windows apps are possible? If so, you can schedule a one-time task with `SCHTASKS` and supply the password as part of the command line. No `SendKeys` necessary.

Comment: @Bond .. Thanks much.... SCHTASKS did the magic for me.. :)

Comment: @Bond -- I used the logic of creating a schtask and adding the run as parameters (including username and password) and it worked... However for some computers/servers, there is a security policy ENABLED which does not allow us to save password's.. When this policy is enabled, the schtask creation fails... Is there any other way to provide automatic password to a RunAs script?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i do not think it is best to use vbscript to send a password. For example if the user were to shift focus to another window, the password would be sent to that window instead. Probably the reason why it does not work on some servers is because another window might have become the active window while the script was running.

If automation is truly needed, it might be better to use AUTOIT. However, with that being said, another method would be to enter this command in a shortcut file.

runas /profile /env /savecred  /user:username pathtofile. Therefore you enter the password manually once and it will always execute as the indicated username afterwards.

Comment: AUTOIT is a third party application which I can not use and savecred worked till XP only (I guess) .. It does not work on Windows 7/8, WIn 2008/2012 .. So can you suggest some other option to auto-enter RunAs password

Comment: savecred has been verified to be working on Windows 7. Can you please double check your command and confirm.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It works However in my case, the DB user is created on the fly and the user never logs into the system. The first time this user is used IS while running the initdb.exe .. so the credentials are never saved... I tried using the `savecred` option with RunAs but it still asks me for a password

Comment: sorry, Im a bit lost as to what you are trying to accomplish. Please correct me if I am wrong: You want to create a script to automate running initdb.exe as an administrator when someone is not logged on to the system, Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
Option explicit
Dim oShell
Const password = "AdministratorPassword"
Const DBUser="localhost\administrator"
set oShell= Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 500
oShell.run "cmd.exe /c  runas /noprofile /user:"&DBUser&" " & WScript.Arguments(0) &""
WScript.Sleep 2000
oShell.SendKeys (password)
WScript.Sleep 300
oShell.SendKeys"~"
Wscript.Quit
```

Run the script from command line to run `notepad.exe` as administrator

```
cscript.exe //nologo //b runasDBUser.vbs notepad.exe
```